# Nuitka standalone isn't really standalone

Tags: python, nuitka

I plan on using a Python (3.6) script for a project, though the final user is likely not to have Python on his system. To solve this issue and make everything as smooth as possible, I tried using Nuitka to compile my Python script and make it standalone.

To do that, I just ran

```
nuitka --standalone --recurse-all myscript.py
```

Doing this takes a certain amount of time, but finally results in a folder with a `myscript.exe` that I can run just like I would run my script.

Though, as soon as I try and run it on another computer, no matter whether it has Python installed, I get an error thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\thoma\Desktop\recuperation.dist\recuperation.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\thoma\Desktop\recuperation.dist\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in requests
  File "D:\Users\thoma\Desktop\recuperation.dist\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in urllib3
  File "D:\Users\thoma\Desktop\recuperation.dist\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in connectionpool
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'
```

Also, I had trouble getting it to work in the beginning, because it was missing `cacert.pem`, but I solved that by copying the `certifi` folder that I found coming with `requests`. Don't know if it relates.

My script is using `Requests`, `Dill`, `BS4` (and also `json`, `base64`, `os` and `sys`)

Comment: have you installed `_socket` using pip ?

Comment: No, I didn't. But the script is working if I just run it with `python36 script.py`

Comment: I can't help with Nuitka specifically, but these are both issues (missing "external files" like the certificate or missing third party packages) that can arise with an inappropriately specified setup.cfg when using distutils or cx_Freeze -- so you might look into whether Nuitka supports that specification and how to edit it

Comment: this means this library might be installed in your system, but nuitka cannot find it. Try installing it locally using pip and then compiling it into an executable

Comment: @jedwards I'll look into it.

Comment: @mrid installing it locally using pip means having Python installed on the target system, which is what I want to avoid by using Nuitka.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski i mean installing it on your dev machine before you compile it. Nuitka will compile it into an exe which you should be able to run on the target system

Comment: @mrid Running `pip install _socket` just throws a lot of red lines

Answer (score 3):

The `--standalone` option does not (yet) produce a single file binary. In order to run `myscript.exe` on another machine, you have to provide all the files you find in the output directory of nuitka.

Luckily there is work in progress to allow compilation to single file binaries: https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/230

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.3 `__init__.py` files are not required in Python modules. Nuitka can sometimes ignore modules in the build based on the presence of these files. A workaround would be to manually add them if they're not there.